# android studio NDK , about cv:: method

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

First, I'm sorry I can not English well. I gave up googling, I was exhausted. Please give me tips.

I just finished NDK's h, cpp, Android.mk and Applicaiton.mk files and then I ran my application. It works well. But by adding one line Mat mat in cpp file, I got the error right away about `cv::Mat~~`

I immediately modified `Mat` to `cv::Mat` but I got other errors about `cv::~~`. I think that I have to write `using namespace cv;`. But this is Android Studio not C++. What should I do??

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := C:\opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\include
LOCAL_MODULE := myCanny
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myCanny.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_MODULED := myCanny
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the output from Android Studio when you built your project?

Comment: @AhiyaHiya  I wll tell you If I success this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just use the java port of openCV?
https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

*If* there is a reason you are using c++ code for image processing, let's talk.
 `somenamespace::function()` is the same if you set `using namespace somenamespace` and just call `function()`, so it's not necessary. 
please share your cpp code to get more detais. maybe, you've forgot to `#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"` ?

Comment: the reason I want to use "using namespace cv;" because of opencv header files.. there are many method related "cv" in opencv header. I can't edit all method